# Will there be lift in a space with atmospheric pressure and no gravity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I think there's always aerodynamics, right? But what can we do without gravitational lift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will there be buoyancy in a space with atmospheric pressure and no gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505463/will-there-be-buoyancy-in-a-space-with-atmospheric-pressure-and-no-gravity)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform no, this is not a duplicate of that question. Buoyancy is not the same as lift. Buoyancy requires a gravitational field - lift from an airfoil (for example) doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Astronauts inside the space station, in free fall could certainly use the reaction force of air to move around. A working model plane could certainly maneuver in atmosphere, in free fall. The hard part would be defining "lift" with no up or down.

Comment: Lift is defined as the component of force perpendicular to the direction of motion, irrespective of the directions of up or down.

Comment: @D.Halsey technically, there is a planar subspace perpendicular to the direction of motion. The orientation of the airfoil is also important.

Comment: @Time4Tea I should have written more carefully. I was just trying to point out that lift did not have to be in a vertical direction.